# Enforce third party methods virtuality

Tags: c++, virtual

I'm extending a class provided by a third part library. The class, let's call it `Foo`, has a `reset()` method which can be called in order to restart `Foo`'s behavior. The `reset()` method is also used internally by the class.

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    void reset () {
        /* ... */
    }
    void something () {
        reset();
    }
};
```

So far, I need to overload the `reset()` method in order to reset my additional features as well:

```
class Bar : public Foo
{
  public:
    void reset() {
        /* ...something... */
        Foo::reset();
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, since the `Foo::reset()` method is not virtual, by calling `Bar::something()` I get the `Foo::reset()` method called instead of `Bar::reset()`.

Is there a way (different from overloading `Foo::something()` as well) to make it backward-virtual?

Comment: By the way, in this way I learnt to always set as virtual any method which is both public and used internally.

Comment: That is a bad decision, google for NVI and you will see a trend into avoiding public virtual methods. The problem you are facing is different: you cannot extend a class that was not designed to be extended.

Comment: I strongly support Non Virtual Interfaces. using `virtual` public methods is akin to returning handles to your internals --> it's a No-No.

Comment: In Bar you're neither overloading (Bar's & Foo's `reset` have the same signature) not overriding it (since Foo's `reset` is not virtual); you're hiding Foo's `reset()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot extend classes that were not intended to be extended.

Answer (score 3):

You can't make `reset()` virtual in your library in such a way that it will affect the base class without changing the base class's code. For starters, the compiler has not added the necessary bookkeeping code that allows it to make virtual calls to `reset()`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'clean way' of doing it using inheritance. Virtual is a compile/link time difference: using a vtable to resolve method at runtime (virtual) vs direct linking (non-virtual).

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible.  The virtualness of a method is decided when the method is declared and you cannot change it later in a base class.

To allow you to do so would be nothing short of a disaster.  Virtual methods simply behave differently than non-virtual methods and it must be accounted for when designing an object.  With this proposal I would have to consider that all of my methods could behave in 2 distinctly different ways.  That significantly adds to the design cost of the application and reduces the reliability.

Answer (score 1):

If neither reset nor something are virtual, you're screwed, and that's the end of the story. If something is virtual you could override it. However, if these necessary methods aren't virtual, then the class isn't intended to be extended (or implemented properly, if it was intended).

Edit:

You COULD try composition, e.g.

```
class Bar {
    Foo f;
    // foo's methods, etc, wrapped here
    void something() {
        f.reset();
        reset();
    }
};
```

But if you need the whole, implicit conversion, thing, you're still stuffed.